# how could the object passed to C++ STL mem_fun_t call the function whose name is defined inside mem_fun_t

Tags: c++, stl

This the code from GNU STL:

```
template<typename _Ret, typename _Tp>
    class mem_fun_t : public unary_function<_Tp*, _Ret>
    {
    public:
      explicit
      mem_fun_t(_Ret (_Tp::*__pf)())
      : _M_f(__pf) { }

      _Ret
      operator()(_Tp* __p) const
      { return (__p->*_M_f)(); }

    private:
      _Ret (_Tp::*_M_f)();
    };
```

Although `__p` has a member function that has the same type with
`_M_f`,how could `__p` call `_M_f`, `__p` don't have a member named `_M_f`.

Comment: Do you understand how pointers to members work? Or what `_M_f` is?

Comment: `_M_f` is a member function pointer variable.

Comment: @T.C. It is just I don't understand how pointers to member work. Would you please tell me?

Comment: @Barmar Why bind _M_f to a class member rather than an object.Is is that all object of the class share the same address to the member function?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_M_f` is a pointer to member function, of type `_Ret(_Tp::*)()`.

It is called through the pointer: `__p->*_M_f)()`.  The dereference operator `*` is very significant there.